# Elimination Method. System of Equations. When it cannot be used?

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

I know that using the **addition property of equality** one can solve systems of equations via **elimination**. Until a couple of days ago, I hadn't thought about any potential constraints of this method. The following system (a system of partial derivatives) is the one that's got me thinking:

$2x^3-x-y=0$

$-2y^3+x+y=0$

**Substituting** $y$ with $2x^3-x$ allows me to solve the system fairly easily (I need only real solutions). However, if I use the **elimination method**, I fail miserably. Clearly I am missing something but I can't figure out what exactly.

I would be grateful if you could help me out. I apologise if the question is silly.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you applied the elimination method? Adding the equations produces $2x^3 - 2y^3 = 0$, which simplifies to $x = y$ (given we're working in $\Bbb{R}$), which seems like a step forward.

Comment: Usually, the method applies to linear systems or to systems with special structure where nonlinear terms cancel out. But here we get a useful extra condition restricting the solutions drastically by adding the two equations.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I got $x=y$, but how can I move forward from it? I assume, in this case, the elimination method can only provide me with a constraint / additional info ($x = y$) but not with a solution?

Comment: So, I still need "a special structure" so as to eliminate particular terms thus making my system easier to solve. This system, I assume, doesn't have it.

Comment: @Moo Many thanks! I have no idea how have I missed it. Appreciate your help!